# Formal Run-time Derivation Of This Algorithm Using Summations

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

Suppose we have the loop

```
for(i=n, i >= 1, i=i/2){
   for(j=1, j <= i, j++){
       constant-op
    }
}
```

I know the number of iterations k, is n/2^k = 1, or k = log(n).

Where I'm confused is modeling this algorithm as a summation, I currently have

Sum from i=n to log(n) of c1 for the outer loop

Sum for j=1 to i of c2 for the inner loop.

Is this accurate? I feel like it's wrong since i is starting at n, and not at 0 like some other examples that I have seen.

After some work, I got the final runtime to be log^2(n), which seems right but not totally sure.

Comment: Fist of all you could simply test your assumption for some n. And yes you are right about  log(n)  loop-iterations are performed (+- a constant).

Comment: Combing the above summations, as Sum from i=n to log(n) of (sum from j = 1 to i of c2) gave me the run-time O(n^2). Seems too large

Comment: Which values of n have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For n=16 I get: 5 loop-executions of the i-loop and alltogether 16+8+4+2+1=31 = 2n-1 'constant-op' s executions. So altogether `O(2n-1)=O(n)`.

For n=1024 you get:
1024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 2048 - 1 = O(n)

I think this way you can easyly see that the 'constant-op' is always performed O(n) times.

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate it:

It is clear that inner loop will be executed:
`n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ... + n/2^k` where `k` is biggest integer which satisfies following equation:

[image: enter link description here]

Without loss of generality you can assume that n = 2^k therefore

[image]

Now you can calculate it as geometrical series so it is

[image: enter link description here]

Now it is clear that it's `O(n)`